# How to wait for ajax call of another element's click event to finish

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call another element's click event inside a click event that basically does a window.location.href = mailto:emailaddress but the problem is the other element has an ajax call and the window.location.href seems to be cancelling the ajax call. Is there an easy way to wait for the ajax call inside the click event to finish before executing the window.location.href in this scenario?

Here is a sample of the html & javascript:

```
<a id="email-link" href="mailto:emailaddress@email.com">emailaddress</a>

<div class="right" id="list-items">
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#list-items').live('click', function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")",
            success: function () {
                console.log('done');
            }
        });
    });

    $('#email-link').live('click', function () {
        //Let's just say it's the first item of the li
        var liItem = $('#list-items li').first();
        var thisLink = $(this);

        window.location.href = thisLink.attr("href");

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simulating a click event, you could externalize the function that performs the main operation and pass a callback function:

```
function doStuff(obj, fn)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")",
        success: function () {
            console.log('done');
            fn && fn();
        }
    });
}

$('#list-items').on('click', function () {
    doStuff(this);
});

$('#email-link').on('click', function () {
    //Let's just say it's the first item of the li
    var liItem = $('#list-items li').get(0),
    url = this.href;

    doStuff(liItem, function() {
        window.location.href = url;
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I didn't know you can pass a function to a function in javascript.

Comment: @SLin Yep, functions are objects too :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback function to tell when the AJAX process has completed.

```
var emailLinkOnClick = function(e) {
    var liItem = $('#list-items li').first();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    listItemsClick(e, function() {
        // this is executed on success of the ajax call
        // inside listItemsClick
        window.location.href = href;
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});

var listItemsClick = function(e, success) {
    $.ajax({
        //does something server side
    }).success(success);
});

$('#list-items').on('click', function(e) {
    listItemsClick(e, function(){
        // you can optionally do something on success here
    });
});

$('#email-link').on('click.redirect', emailLinkOnClick);
```

Comment: Tried the new code you wrote up, it still doesn't work. The liItem.click() is called but the window redirect is cancelling the ajax call.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a recent version of jQuery, `$.ajax` returns a Promise, so you can use `.when` and `.then`

```
$('#email-link').live('click', function () {
    var self = this;   
    var liItem = $('#list-items li').first();

    $.when(liItem.click()).then(function () {
        window.location.href = $(self).attr("href");
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/e42yK/)

Comment: I've tried this already actually, it doesn't seem to help. In my network debugging, I still see the ajax call being cancelled and while debugging the javascript there is no pause at all. Do I need a special library to use jQuery deferred?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.7.2.min.js straight from Google's library.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need a special library. Have you manipulated the global ajax configuration?

Comment: No I haven't touched anything in regards to the global ajax configurations. I just tried everything in a new MVC 4 internet app with the same html and it still doesn't wait for the ajax call to finish.

Comment: Is your app on a public facing webserver? Also, have you tried @J.Money's suggestion?

Comment: No, I don't have the app available to the public. I tried J.Money's new suggestion and it doesn't work either. I may just have to face the ugly workaround of somehow copying the ajax call code into the email click and putting the window.location.href into the success.